# What are these incidents mentioned by Lord Shiva as examples of helping his devotees?

Tags: shiva, rishi, shiva-purana, kings, kamarupa

While reading the **[Shiva Purana Rudra Samhita Parvati Khanda](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226088.html)** I came across the following declarations by the Lord:

> The vow of the king of Assam (Kāmarūpa) was made fruitful.
> I saved king Sudakṣiṇā who had become a hireling and a prisoner.
> I am the three-eyed God who bestows happiness but brought about the misery of Gautama. I especially curse those wicked persons who harass my devotees.

**Are there any details in the scriptures regarding these incidents involving the below:**

1. The King of Kamarupa
2. King named Sudakshina
3. Gautam Rishi

Comment: Two of these indicents are main reasons of Shiva mansifested as Bhimeshvara and Tryambakeshwara.

Comment: @Boovanaes Can you share the details as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

The same Shiva Purana mention these incidents of Lord Shiva saving his devotees.

The [20](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226521.html) & [21](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226522.html)st chapters of Kotirudra Samhita mentiones the incident of Shiva saving king Sudakshina in connection to the appearance of the Nageshwara jyotirlinga. The king of Kamarupa who adorned Shiva in the Bhimeshwara jyotirlinga was imprisoned by Kumbhakarna's son, Bhimasura. But later, Lord Shiva freed him after killing Bhimasura.

And, the [24](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226525.html), [25](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226526.html) and [26](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226527.html)th chapters of Kotirudra Samhita mentiones the incident of  Gautama Maharishi in connection to the appearance of the Tryambakeshwara jyotirlinga .

You can ask why i never mentioned the King of Kamarupa. Because, Sudakshina is the king of Kamarupa and his vow as follows (according to 21st Chapter of Kotirudra Samhita):-

> 24. I am a wicked ignorant brute in your eyes **but I shall never forsake Śiva. My lord who is the most excellent of all will never forsake me.**

So, it is confirmed that King of Kamarupa and Sudakshina is same and one person.

Ok that's it. I hope your doubt was cleared now.

Comment: Great please add the reference links to make the answer complete.